# How to convert given latitude and longitude to distance travel in KM

Tags: r

My project has given latitudes and longitudes for each travel route and I would like to know the function to covert it to distance travel in KM.

column name are: start_lat, start_lng, end_lat, end_lng

start_lat: 42.08000
start_lng: -87.68000
end_lat: 42.07000
end_lng: -87.69000

Is distGeo the right choice?

If you could explain, it'd be much appreciated

TIA

Comment: take a look at the distance funstions from the `geosphere` and the `sf`-packages

Answer (score 1):

use the geosphere, of the sf-package

```
# put points in a named vector
start <- c(lon = -87.68000, lat = 42.08000)
end   <- c(lon = -87.69000, lat = 42.07000)

#geosphere solution
library(geosphere)
geosphere::distGeo(start, end)
# [1] 1385.125

# sf solution
library(sf)
rbind(start, end) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  st_distance()
# Units: [m]
#          [,1]     [,2]
# [1,]    0.000 1384.797
# [2,] 1384.797    0.000
```